# Windows 10 version 1703 update ask to remove CheckPoint SecuRemote / VPN

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1703, checkpoint-endpoint

I can't work without CheckPoint VPN and Windows 10 version 1703 update prompt me to remove CheckPoint VPN:

[image]

I have old  E80.51 version of CheckPoint.

For latest E80.64, E80.65 versions [Check Point Endpoint Security Client support for Microsoft Windows 10 Updates](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk111274) page says:

> 1703     Creators Update     Redstone 2  Planned for Q2 2017

Is it right that I should postpone *1703 Creators Update* until CheckPoint provide solution?

Are there any other alternatives (I use password based authentication)?

**UPDATE**

[Update 1604 for Configuration Manager Technical Preview – Available Now!](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/04/22/update-1604-for-configuration-manager-technical-preview-available-now/) says:

> VPN for Windows 10 – You can now deploy VPN profiles with 3rd-party providers to Windows 10 devices managed with **ConfigMgr client**. These providers include Pulse Secure, F5 Edge, Dell SonicWall, and **Checkpoint**.

What does that mean?

**UPDATE 2** I tried [Check Point Capsule VPN available for Windows 10](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk107536) but not succeed to connect.

Latest available E80.65 version also is banned by Microsoft Update. I postpone update until solution become available.

See also [Windows 10 Support Plan for Check Point Products](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk107036)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Checkpoint engineer answered to wait for new Checkpoint build:

[Upgrade to Windows 10 Creators Update, Check Point Mobile not compatible](https://forums.checkpoint.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=26965)

that should be released soon.

40 days left from that statement... here it is  [E80.70 Remote Access Clients for Windows](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=55515)

For those who still want to defer update the best solution is to stop Update Service:

```
cmd> sc stop wuauserv
cmd> sc config wuauserv start= disabled
```

Other details here: [Deferring updates in Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703)](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10-creators-update-version-1703/)

Answer (score 3):

[E80.70 Remote Access Clients for Windows](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal/user/anon/page/default.psml/media-type/html?action=portlets.DCFileAction&eventSubmit_doGetdcdetails=&fileid=55515)

E80.70 was released on Sunday. I was able to install Windows 10 version 1703 after updating to E80.70. VPN works, at least on our corporate setup.

Comment: Your answer works for a comment

Comment: It is valuable answer. For those who have great troubles because of update. +1

Answer (score 3):

According to Checkpoint Support Center, Windows 10 1703 (AKA Creators Update) is officially supported with Check Point Endpoint Security Client version E80.70.

Fall Creators Update Windows 10 1709 is still [not supported](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk111274).

You can download Checkpoint VPN client E80.70 from [here](https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk117155).

If an unsupported version of the Client is installed it may be the reason to Windows 10 Upgrade 1703 errors, like this one that I got from System Center 1702:
0xC1900208(-1047526904)

Release changes from Checkpoint:

> What's New in E80.70
>
> This release supports all Software Blades and features of previous
>   releases. It adds support for Windows 10 Creators Update (version
>   1703) and support for new VPN and improved features.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound you were right, I edited the answer to Windows 10 1709, according to Microsoft documentation, that's the official number https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1709

Answer (score 0):

If you have a service contract with CheckPoint, you can download E80.70 as Early Availability (BETA) that works with Creators Update.

Answer (score 0):

Check Point Endpoint Security client version E80.72 works fine with the 2017 Fall Creators Update of Windows 10 (version 1709/build 16299).

http://supportcontent.checkpoint.com/file_download?id=60349

Comment: Yeah, I updated to this version as I've got yet another warning about incompatibility...

Answer (score -1):

Similar issue faced --- New client released by Checkpoint
Enterprise Endpoint Security E80.72 Windows Clients:

https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk122093&partition=General&product=Endpoint#What's%20New%20in%20E80.72