# Deferring updates in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates, group-policy

In Windows 10 version 1607, it was still possible to defer updates by a few months via the Local Group Policy Editor, but now there's a subfolder containing two entries where it's only possible to defer them by 30-60 days with a maximum of 365 days (timer has to be set anew every time).

Am I seeing this correct or am I missing something?

And what's the difference between *feature* and *quality* updates?

Comment: Your missing something. You can still defer the next feature update for 6 months on 1703 but additionally you can defer security updates for a shorter amount of time (15 days).  Quality updates are the .xxx build updates, functional or "feature" updates are (1703,1607,1511)

Comment: I only ever deferred updates through Windows Update.  The name of the two policies would involve more research then I have time to do so perhaps based off my explanation somebody can submit an answer

Comment: Regarding the new `Group Policy` settings, Microsoft has authored explanations regarding the new configuration that are primarily aimed at business environments, but they should still help clarify things for you:  [Pause Feature Updates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/update/waas-configure-wufb#pause-feature-updates) as well as [Pause Quality Updates](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/update/waas-configure-wufb#pause-quality-updates).

Comment: It should be made clear only Enterprise and Education can defer either update type forever through a group policy.  Even the updates are still required, it's just those variants, respect the policy setting.  Only exception is using a WSUS on a Professional, since you would configure the image, to download the updates from your WSUS not Microsoft.  If you need to stay at a feature update build, use the LTSB, you get the typical 5+5 life cycle

Comment: Quality Rollups also exist on Windows 7/Windows 8.1 which contain the cumulative updates released in the past 30 days + previous months (if they are not installed) but the build number doesn't chnage for 7/8,1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After the introduction of Windows 10 version 1703 (released in April 2017), Microsoft provided us with additional options to defer updates within the Professional, Enterprise, or Education editions of their operating system.  While you can still utilize the **Local Group Policy Editor**, now you can also use the **Settings** app to achieve the same goal.

First, let's establish the difference between a Windows 10 **Feature Update** and a **Quality Update**:

## Windows 10 Feature Updates versus Quality Updates

> **Feature Updates** - They are actually much more like an entire operating system *upgrade* than an update and typically provide new functionality. [Examples of new features](https://www.howtogeek.com/353165/whats-new-in-windows-10s-redstone-5-update-available-fall-2018/) found within Windows 10 version 1809 (the October 2018 Update) include the [Clipboard History and Cloud Sync](https://www.howtogeek.com/351978/using-windows-10s-new-clipboard-history-and-cloud-sync/) feature, the [New Screenshot Tool](https://www.howtogeek.com/352290/using-windows-10s-new-screenshot-tool-clips-and-annotations/), and the addition of a [Dark Theme to File Explorer](https://www.howtogeek.com/fyi/microsoft-adds-a-dark-theme-to-file-explorer-in-the-latest-windows-10-update/). Microsoft has said that ["Windows is committing to a predictable twice-per-year feature release schedule,"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2017/04/20/windows-office-align-feature-release-schedules-benefit-customers/) targeting March and September of each year. A Feature Update will actually increment the [Windows 10 version number](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10/release-information): the original Windows 10 release was version 1507 and was subsequently superseded by version 1511, 1607, 1703, 1709, 1803, and now 1809.
>
> **Quality Updates** - These provide Windows 10 with security patches & bug fixes, are cumulative, and are normally released on a monthly basis (usually on [Patch Tuesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday)). In contrast to the Feature Updates, a Windows 10 Quality Update will increment the [OS build number](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10/release-information): Windows 10 version 1803 (the April 2018 Update) began as build number 17134.**1**, and it has subsequently been updated to 17134.**648**.

## Deferring Updates using the Local Group Policy Editor

Turning our attention to the **Local Group Policy Editor**, [Microsoft tells us](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-configure-wufb) that starting with Windows 10 version 1607 (released in August 2016) the pertinent Group Policies for deferring Windows Updates can be found in the following location:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Defer Windows Updates
```

[image: Defer Windows Updates]

You can easily configure the appropriate settings to defer both **Feature Updates** and **Quality Updates** within that interface.

---

Notably, after the debut of Windows 10 version 1709 (released in October 2017) the hierarchy of Group Policies for deferring Windows Updates was changed to the following location:

```
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Windows Update for Business
```

[image: Windows Update for Business]

The same options are readily available for both **Feature Updates** and **Quality Updates** in the new Group Policy layout, and Microsoft also added new capabilities for managing when you receive a new Windows 10 Insider Preview Build (for those of us who are participating in that program).

## Deferring Updates using the Settings App

As a potentially superior alternative, Microsoft [emphasizes the benefits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-configure-wufb) of using the revamped **Settings** app to achieve the same goals:

> Starting with Windows 10 version 1703, pausing through the settings app will provide a more consistent experience:
>
> - Any active restart notifications are cleared or closed
> - Any pending restarts are canceled
> - Any pending update installations are canceled
> - Any update installation running when pause is activated will attempt to rollback

That being said, if you have the Professional, Enterprise, or Education edition of Windows 10 version 1703 (or newer), you can utilize this new capability to **pause updates** [in the following manner](https://www.howtogeek.com/286658/how-to-change-how-long-updates-are-deferred-in-windows-10/):

> **How to Pause Updates**
>
> Windows can pause updates for 35 days. After the period expires, Windows 10 automatically unpauses, looks for updates, and begins installing them. Windows will need to install the latest updates before you can pause updates once again.
>
> To pause updates, head to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > Advanced Options. Scroll down and turn on the “Pause Updates” option.
>
> [image: Pause Updates]

On the other hand, the remodeled `Settings` app will also allow you to **defer updates** [using the following technique](https://www.howtogeek.com/286658/how-to-change-how-long-updates-are-deferred-in-windows-10/):

> **How to Defer Updates**
>
> To defer updates, head to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > Advanced Options. Scroll down and use the “Feature update” and “Quality update” options under “Choose when updates are installed” to specify how many days you want to defer updates for. Set these options back to “0” to stop deferring updates.
>
> [image: Defer Feature and Quality Updates]

Notice that you are also afforded the opportunity to [choose between two distinct groups](https://www.howtogeek.com/286658/how-to-change-how-long-updates-are-deferred-in-windows-10/) that help determine when **Feature Updates** will be installed:

> This page also lets you switch from the **Semi-Annual Channel
> (Targeted)**, which was formerly known as the Current Branch, to the
> **Semi-Annual Channel**, which was formerly known as the Current Branch
> for Business.
>
> The default Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted) option means you’ll get
> updates when they’re being provided to consumer PCs. If you switch to
> the Semi-Annual Channel, you’ll only get updates after they’ve been
> more thoroughly tested and Microsoft feels they’re ready for
> Enterprise deployment. This often happens about four months after the
> update is released to consumers.
>
> If you select the Semi-Annual Channel and also decide that Feature Updates *"can be deferred for this many days,"* the combined effect is cumulative. So, if you switch to the Semi-Annual Channel and defer feature updates
> for 365 days, your computer will receive updates a year after they appear in the
> Semi-Annual channel. In other words, it will take about 16 months for
> an update to be installed on your PC after it first rolls out to consumer PCs.
>
> [image: Choose when updates are installed]

## Local Group Policy Editor's Visible Effect upon the Settings App

By comparison, if you decide to use the **Local Group Policy Editor** to defer updates you will see the equivalent options in the **Settings** interface grayed-out, but still displaying your new modifications:

[image: Advanced options]

## Conclusion

Ultimately the choice is yours, but now that Microsoft has updated the Windows 10 **Settings** interface to allow you to to pause or defer Windows Updates with essentially the same level of fidelity as the **Local Group Policy Editor**, it is probably the easier method.

---

**Sources**:
[Windows 10 Release Information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10/release-information)
[Overview of Windows as a service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-overview)
[Windows 10 - Pause Feature Updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-configure-wufb#pause-feature-updates)
[Windows 10 - Pause Quality Updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-configure-wufb#pause-quality-updates)
[How to Pause and Defer Updates on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/286658/how-to-change-how-long-updates-are-deferred-in-windows-10/)
[What’s New in Windows 10’s October 2018 Update](https://www.howtogeek.com/353165/whats-new-in-windows-10s-redstone-5-update-available-fall-2018/)

Comment: no feature update are like NEW Windows version in the past with new features (1607, 1703 are feature updates with new features to Windows10) Service packs only bundled all available updates, this is no longer required because now all updates are cumulative.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Update Service:

```
cmd> sc stop wuauserv
cmd> sc config wuauserv start= disabled
```

Apply registry settings:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
; "ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate"=dword:00000001
"BranchReadinessLevel"=dword:00000010
"DeferFeatureUpdates"=dword:00000001
"DeferFeatureUpdatesPeriodInDays"=dword:000000b4
"PauseFeatureUpdates"=dword:00000001
; "DeferQualityUpdates"=dword:00000001
; "DeferQualityUpdatesPeriodInDays"=dword:0000001e
; "PauseQualityUpdates"=dword:00000001
```

I am not sure if they are working for Windows 10 Home edition. [Official documentation for those switches](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-configure-wufb).

See also blog https://tweakhound.com/2016/10/23/delaying-windows-10-updates/

Comment: You cannot defer updates on Windows 10 home but I am not entirely sure how this differs from the existing answer

Comment: @Ramhound Disabling Update service causes Windows to shut up. But that breaks some functionality (Windows complaints about missing services when you try to change some configs).