# How to get Windows 10 Long Term Service Branch (LTSB)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I am planning to transfer from Windows 7 to Windows 10 (maybe this is not a good idea). I heard that Windows 10 is not as stable as Windows 7, then the only choice is Windows 10 Long Term Service Branch (LTSB).

Where can I download the LTSB? Must I pay additional money for this version?

My Dell laptop has a Windows 10 Pro tag.

Comment: It may be easier to configure your Windows 10 Pro to [defer updates](https://superuser.com/q/1199677/650163) so that your configuration changes are a bit more stable.  You can even setup your OS so that you are utilizing the `Current Branch for Business` (CBB), all within your Windows 10 Pro settings.  The CBB Feature Updates occur several months after the mainstream public receives them for stability purposes.  Additional reading that is beneficial:  [How to Pause and Defer Updates on Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/286658/how-to-change-how-long-updates-are-deferred-in-windows-10/)

Comment: If this is a reasonably recent Dell PC, and it came with a Pro license, you should be able to download the complete Windows image, that include all your drivers and utilities, from Dell's support portal.  I was pleasantly surprised that they now have these download images available.

Comment: LTSB is only available for volume license customers, no end users.

Comment: *I heard that Windows 10 is not as stable as Windows 7*...That sounds like an opinion that lacks supporting empirical evidence. I would be careful about believing unqualified statements such as this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB is only intended for purpose-fit machines (e.g. POS terminals, ATMs, digital signage, medical devices, etc.) and should not be used on consumer machines. Consequently, it is not available through traditional retail channels. If you're looking to upgrade, Windows 10 Home or Pro is likely what you're looking for.

However, a 90 day free trial for LTSB is [available for download on TechNet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise). You'll need to log in with a Microsoft account and register specifically for evaluation. Use beyond the trial period will require a volume license agreement with Microsoft.

Comment: Windows LTSB actually has some strong arguments for itself: no f-ing Cortana, no Windows Store, the ability to disable Windows Update (although I apparently managed to do that on my Win Pro at work), 10 years of security updates without pesky feature changes. It is definitely fit for consumer machines, and you would be able to keep a static (feature-wise) yet up-to-date (security-wise) OS during the whole lifetime of your device. Not allowing the general public to buy it is purely a marketing strategy.

Comment: @user14764 Worth noting that LTSB doesn't excclude you from updates... Just the annoying, pointless ones. You still get security and related patches, but you get no new features / updates like the Anniversary Edition. The feature set is stable and constant. Frankly, I can't think of anything better

Comment: Although this is the correct answer it is a bad one. The correct answer is: Microsoft doesn't want you to have a version which isn't a Trojan horse (you get the gist) unless you are a big company that pays very well for exactly that. There are NO valid arguments against LTSB when compared to regular Spyware10!

Answer (score 4):

LTSB is available only in the Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB edition. This build of Windows doesn’t contain many in-box applications, such as Microsoft Edge, Windows Store client, Cortana (limited search capabilities remain available), Microsoft Mail, Calendar, OneNote, Weather, News, Sports, Money, Photos, Camera, Music, and Clock. Therefore, it’s important to remember that Microsoft has positioned the LTSB model primarily for specialized devices.

Microsoft never publishes feature updates through Windows Update on devices that run Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB. Instead, it typically offers new LTSB releases every 2–3 years, and organizations can choose to install them as in-place upgrades or even skip releases over a 10-year life cycle.

If you want to use LTSB, you need to pay for it, but you could register a Microsoft account to download an 90 days Evaluation version, only on trial.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise

Comment: `This build of Windows doesn’t contain many in-box applications....` - That'll save me my first hour of setup then...

Comment: `This build of Windows doesn’t contain many in-box applications, such as...` Sounds fantastic.

Comment: How does the VLSC cost to get the LTSB if you're just a single developer?