# Is there something like LTS in Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, lifespan

Ubuntu and perhaps some other GNU/Linux distributions too, have a concept of **LTS**. Is there something similar for Windows?

Usually, lifetime for LTS is fixed per distro. Windows doesn't seem to say anything about its version lifetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any amount life-time defined?

Yes. They can't support a Windows version indefinitely after all. Previously each Windows release has mainstream support for several years, and then some more years of extended support. The supported time depends on the decision from the management instead of a fixed-cycle like on Linux. In some cases they've also had to increased the supported time span due to various reasons (in case of XP, it's because no one wants to use Vista). For the supporting timeline check the below links

- [List of Microsoft Windows versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions)
- [Windows lifecycle fact sheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet)

But since Windows 10 they've switched to a [Windows-as-a-service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-quick-start) model, which is like [rolling release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_release) in Linux. So now they have to introduced a more stable branch for enterprises who want robustness named *Long Term Servicing branch*, which means the answer to the question

> Is there anything same in MS Windows?

is **yes**. In 2018 the branch has been renamed to *Long-Term Servicing Channel* (LTSC)

> ## [Overview of Windows as a service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-overview)
>
> As part of the alignment with Windows 10 and Office 365 ProPlus, we are adopting common terminology to make it as easy as possible to understand the servicing process. Going forward, these are the new terms we will be using:
>
> - Semi-Annual Channel - We will be referring to Current Branch (CB) as "Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted)", while Current Branch for Business (CBB) will simply be referred to as "Semi-Annual Channel".
> - Long-Term Servicing Channel - The Long-Term Servicing Branch (LTSB) will be referred to as Long-Term Servicing Channel (LTSC).

## See also

- [Windows 10 release branches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Release_branches)
- [Understanding the Long Term Servicing Branch and Current Branch in Windows 10](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-10/understanding-long-term-servicing-branch-and-current-branch-windows-10)
- [FAQ: Windows 10 LTSB explained](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3250464/faq-windows-10-ltsb-explained.html)
- [How to get Windows 10 Long Term Service Branch (LTSB)?](https://superuser.com/q/1204268/241386)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a Support Lifecycle page, where you can look per-product.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/hub/4095338/microsoft-lifecycle-policy

Comment: This answer misses the first question. But thanks for the next one :)

Answer (score -1):

You have LTS in Linux because you have new versions every year (or twice a year) and some people/institutions require some stability. Changes in Window versions are about 3 years apart and are pretty close to the LTS concept. Win7 is from late 2009/early 2010; and Ubuntu 10.04 support ended in 2015, so it was supported for a longer time. The lifespan of recent RHEL releases is somewhat longer (but is it necessary? the hardware will fail before that).