# Windows 10 Home edition - security updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

We use normal windows licenses on some of our machines. When windows update assistant comes on (which we can't stop anymore as of Windows-As-A-Service), it wants a security update installed. It doesn't turn back on without user interaction currently which we can't do.

We want the following flow if possible. A few solutions we've found works for units on our internal network, or a windows server or enterprise editions instead of home edition.

1. Go onto computer with teamviewer
2. Say "please update"
3. It restarts, installs updates, with no user interaction whatsoever, restarts again
4. Logs back in normally.

But it doesn't seem to happen this way, always sticks on the 3rd step.

EDIT: the problem is that even upon successful update, it asks to accept license before actually starting.

Comment: To my knowledge this is indeed not possible in a home version of windows. You can of course enable auto-login, but it will not start applications that were already open.

Comment: @LPChip Even then, I don't think this works - we do auto login already. And it doesn't start back up :p maybe it's just always crashing when we try to update....

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, are you actually utilizing **Windows 10 Home** within a work environment?  If so, why?

Comment: We have a consumer software that can be used for enterprises. To reduce dev time and maintenance we just maintain it on windows 10 home. That software also happens to be useful for enterprise clients though and until now with forced (really coercive) updates we've never had issues with this method.

Comment: I understand the rationale for what you are doing and we are always glad to help, but hopefully someone else within your IT leadership team anticipated the possibility that you might run into problems trying to manage Windows 10 Home operating systems in a corporate environment.

Comment: @jQwierdy something is going wrong then. If you use netplwiz to setup auto login, it should normally auto login on reboot. The only reason that would fail, is if the user changed their password, or it was setup incorrectly.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that what some of us might label *"really coercive updates"* are specifically designed to protect consumers who are connected to the Internet and using Windows 10 Home without the benefit of corporate firewalls or proxy servers to help protect them.  In contrast, if the machine is utilizing Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education, you can actually [defer Windows Updates](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10-creators-update-version-1703/1199780#1199780) relatively easily.

Comment: Guys, I understand that. But windows updates break. Often. that's what we are finding, it doesn't restart because it errors on update. Then it rolls back, but requires manual input for that. That wouldn't change whatever license we had, would it?

Comment: Then fix windows update. Rebuild the update cache, or in worst case, reinstall windows.

Comment: LPChip, I appreciate it. I'll try to rebuild update cache, but reinstalling isn't really viable in our case.

Comment: @LPChip maybe the added edit at the top helped, if we could remove the need for user accepting license before restarting that would solve the problem.

Comment: @jQwierdy - You can defer the monthly security updates up to 14 days.  You should still be installing them after you have tested them.

Comment: `But windows updates break. Often.`  As the old saying goes, *"not on my watch."*  I really don't see any consistent problems with the Windows 10 updates on my networks.  That being said, we thoroughly test any new Windows updates prior to allowing them to install on our Windows 10 Enterprise workstations.  That is the standard operating procedure in a corporate environment.  At the risk of sounding repetitive, from my perspective using Windows 10 Home in a work environment will typically cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Run5k Agreed. The only option here is an upgrade to windows 10 Pro. Its not even a wanted scenario anymore, to solve this problem, its a necessity.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks guys! I appreciate it the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible.

Windows 10 Home edition is simply not equipped with the settings. Your problem is that some windows updates ask for permission to install, and this permission flag can be altered using group policy. Unfortunately, Group Policy is not a function of Windows 10 Home, which is why you also cannot make the pc join a domain.

Either live with it, or better, upgrade the affected machines to Windows 10 Pro.

Small note: Windows 10 Home is supposed to be used at home. At home people want to accept these so they are in control. In a work environment, the corporation wants to be in control, which is why you can use features like Group Policy to automatically accept these, etc.