# Win 10 1803 update has killed Japanese language keyboard

Tags: language-pack, windows-10-v1803

I have Japanese users in my group and once win 10 1803 is installed the language pack fails to work properly

Tried the install on a fresh install and it also does not work. Any ideas other than rolling back which I am doing as we speak - still this can't be left broken.

Comment: To be specific the keyboard does not allow Japanese typing!!

Comment: What error do you see after installing language pack in lates windows version?

Comment: It does not show an error just doesn't allow for Japanese character typing

Comment: Since version 1803 isn't being automatically pushed until 8 May 2018, I assume that you are testing this build for capability?  This isn't the first Super User post we have seen regarding keyboard language issues related to the 1803 release.  In a worst-case scenario, you can always configure your machines to [defer the update](https://superuser.com/a/1199780/650163).

Answer (score 1):

Copy `C:\Windows\IME\IMEJP\DICTS` from a non 1803 machine. It completely resolved the issue for me.

For whatever reason, the 1803 update jacked up the Japanese dictionary -- thus it didn't know what characters to type.