# Microsoft Edge doesn't get updated with Windows updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, microsoft-edge

I have `Microsoft EdgeHTML 15.15063`, but I want to update to the latest stable release of [EdgeHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdgeHTM). I regularly apply Windows updates, but the browser hasn't been getting updated automatically, despite the fact that it's the only way I know of to update the browser.

Is there a way to download a manual patch? Or is there something that might prevent Edge from getting updates?

I have Windows 10 Enterprise.

**My solution:** Thanks for the information. I have accepted the answer that led me to discover the actual problem. I found that my version update was failing. I ran `chkdsk /r` (which found and repaired a problem with Windows Update) and rebooted. My updates were able to be successfully installed after that.

Comment: The browser will only get updated within a Windows 10 [Feature Update](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10/1199780#1199780).  Have you been installing those, also?  When you navigate to `Start > Run` and type `winver`, which version (1511, 1607, etc.) of Windows 10 do you see?

Comment: *I have Windows 10 Enterprise* -> So, is this a work PC? Is it in a domain?

Comment: @Run5k - The author is running 1703 based on the version [EdgeHTML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new/edgehtml-15) they are using. [EdgeHTML17 because Microsoft docs are stupid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide)

Comment: If this version of Enterprise is also the Long Term Servicing Branch (LTSB), then you won't be able to do any Windows 10 upgrades yourself

Comment: @egray - Author is using EdgeHTML 15, which means they are using 1703, and the previous Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB is based on 1607, not 1703.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to update to the latest stable release of EdgeHTML.

If you want the current stable release of EdgeHTML, it means you must upgrade your installation, to Windows 10 1709 or Windows 10 1803.  EdgeHTML 17 is technically the current version, but EdgeHTML 16, is considered the current stable version.

- Windows 10 April 2018 Update includes EdgeHTML 17

  - [What's new in EdgeHTML 17](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide)
- Windows 10 Fall Creators Update includes EdgeHTML 16

  - [What's new in EdgeHTML 16](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new/edgehtml-16)

> Is there a way to download a manual patch?

You can manually download the current 1709 or 1803 Windows 10 ISO.  However, EdgeHTML 16 and EdgeHTML 17, can only run on their respected versions.

**In other words, it is not possible to update EdgeHTML 15, which is included in the Windows 10 Creators Update (1703), to a newer version unless you upgrade Windows to the respected version.**

> I regularly apply Windows updates, but the browser hasn't been getting
>   updated automatically, despite the fact that it's the only way I know
>   of to update the browser.

If you have installed all the currently released cumulative updates for Windows 10 Version 1703 then you have the current version of EdgeHTML 15.  *If you have KB4103731 installed, then you are running 15063.1088, which means you are using the current version of EdgeHTML 15.*

Comment: If you are connected to a domain, and you do not have authorization and permission to install a newer version of Windows, then what want should not be accomplished by you.  As an Administrator, if a user with access to my network performed an unauthorized upgrade, they would have their access to said network permanently revoked.  There would not be a conversation, they would immediately lose access, and their inability to do work wouldn't be my concern.  Any discussion, with said user about their action, would be immediately reported to their supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, IE was *part* of Windows, but I believe IE and also Edge are now separate MS products. In the Windows Update Advanced Options dialog, check `Give me updates for other Miscrosoft products when I update Windows.`

[image: Update MS products]

Also check any third-party privacy tool you might be using, such as O&O [ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10), to verify that updates for MS products are enabled.