# How to suppress a windows 10 update to my network driver?

Tags: windows-10, drivers

I just noticed that Windows wants to update my network driver (see below).

I do NOT want this update. This driver version was already on my system, and I had to roll back to an earlier version to fix miracast.

How do I get this driver suppressed.... forever?

[image]

Comment: First, you should be able to [pause Windows updates](https://superuser.com/a/1199780/650163) to cancel the pending install.  After that, you can [prevent Windows from automatically updating specific drivers](https://www.howtogeek.com/263851/how-to-prevent-windows-from-automatically-updating-specific-drivers/).

Answer (score 0):

Per comment above, I reviewed all proposed options and went with [this one](https://www.howtogeek.com/263851/how-to-prevent-windows-from-automatically-updating-specific-drivers/).