# Windows 10 doesn't show full icon text nor dots at the end

Tags: windows-10, desktop

I've switched to Windows 10 recently and I'm having issues with icon texts on the desktop. Short names are displayed correctly but long ones are replaced by dots at the end. But size something between doesn't show correctly and the name is cut off. But after selecting the icon, the text will expand and everything looks normal until deselection.

There is an image for better understanding:

[image: example]

What I'm trying to achieve is to see a full name or dots at the end (in this case, full text "Malwarebytes" or "Malwareby..." without clicking on it)

Comment: Wait until Microsoft fixes the bug in the next release?

Comment: I don't know if it's a Windows 10 bug or just something wrong in my settings which can be fixed.

Comment: I'm fairly sure it is a bug in 1803.

Comment: If that is the case, I'll wait for another release and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: It is [working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COlLA.jpg) on my Windows 10 version 1709 machines.  I hate to belabor the point, but from my perspective it really is a good idea to [defer Windows 10 Feature Updates](https://superuser.com/a/1199780/650163).  Based upon my settings, I won't receive the version 1803 update until August 9th.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following workaround to try. It can show longer name, but not in the original desktop.

Create a shortcut to your desktop folder C:\Users\Your_Username\Desktop (default location) on the desktop or in the taskbar.

And you can open the shortcut to open or view desktop, and it will show more lines no matter you click the icons.