# How to find out what Win10 update just did?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I just spent 1h 15m waiting for my newly installed `Windows 10` (my work computer, not an OS of my own choice) to start as a result of a "system update".

**Q1:** How can I get a detailed report of what was done during the course of this rather lengthy update? I would like to know whether it was all Microsoft updates or there were updates forced my company.

**Q2:** Where can I go to view the updates repositories that my OS checks for updates? I imaging one is shared in the cloud (Microsoft) and one is the company? I want to see if there is a way for me to control the update policies etc.

Comment: If the update took this long, it is most likely not an update, but upgrade. Aka, new build of Windows 10. If that is the case, going to start->settings->update and security->updates will show no updates, as it is a clean build. Otherwise, you can list all the updates it installed there.

Comment: @LPChip, that is good feedback (as always).  In my experience, if this actually was a [Feature Update](https://superuser.com/a/1199780/650163) on a pre-existing Windows 10 machine, it will still appear as the only entry under `Start > Settings > Update & security > Windows Update > Update history` as follows:  [Update history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg4Nr.png)

Comment: @Run5k ah, yeah... the most recent feature updates are indeed listed as update. You're right.

Comment: @LPChip, no worries my friend.  It's a relatively minor thing, but it could help provide the OP with a definitive reason for the lengthy update.

Answer (score 1):

You can three ways to see the latest Windows Update installed.

One: For command-line
    `C:\WINDOWS\system32>systeminfo.exe`
Or `C:\WINDOWS\system32>systeminfo.exe | find "KB"`

Two: For Powershell
 `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-hotfix`

Three: For Windows Update Settings
1. Open the Windows **Settings**.
2. Click on **Update & security**.
3. Click on the "**Update history**" link located under the Windows Update tab.

Hope it will help you.