# In Win 10 update options, what exactly does “It can be deferred for this many days” mean?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

In Windows 10, Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > Advanced Options > Choose when updates are installed, there are these two options:

> A feature update includes new capabilities and improvements. It can be deferred for this many days: [0-365]
>
> A quality update includes security improvements. It can be deferred for this many days: [0-30]

Screenshot:[image: screenshot]

Phrasing it with “can” is confusing, so I want to know exactly what that number does.

If an update is released to my channel on day *d*, and I've set those options to *n* days, will the update be ...
pushed to me on day *d+n*?
pushed to me sometime between *d* and *d+n*, inclusive, at MS's discretion?
offered to me on *d*, but I'll be able to dismiss it until *d+n*?
Something else?

Note that [a lot of sites](https://www.google.com/search?q=defer+windows+updates) have instructions for setting these options, including [Microsoft themselves](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026834/windows-10-defer-feature-updates) and [this otherwise comprehensive Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10/1199780#1199780). None of those clearly state what effect the numbers have, just that they “defer updates by this many days”.

Comment: Please note that the *"otherwise comprehensive Super User answer"* emphasizes the following:  **If you select the Semi-Annual Channel and also decide that Feature Updates "can be deferred for this many days," the combined effect is cumulative. So, if you switch to the Semi-Annual Channel and defer feature updates for 365 days, you’ll receive updates a year after they appear in the Semi-Annual channel.** In other words, when the deferral timeframe is configured your machine will *install* that update *X* number of days *after* the mainstream group of computers within that channel receives them.

Comment: To utilize your parlance, it will be *"pushed to you on day d+n."*  Please don't read too much into the word "can," either.  That simply means that the graphic interface is affording you the *opportunity* to defer that category of Windows Update a certain number of days.  In other words, you *can* delay the install of an update by the number of days that you select.  And no, it won't be offered to you sooner than that.

Comment: after you defer the time to a d+n days, the feature update and security update will reminder to update system, and at last your system will be pushed.

Comment: @Run5k So they're trying to say “You *can* defer for 0–365 days. How long do you want to defer?”?

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 that is essentially what they are saying.  By default, the number of days to defer is set to `0`.  Personally, I configure the Windows 10 machines on my home network to utilize the **Semi-Annual Channel** with an extra 30-day deferral on the Feature Updates.  That way, my computers avoided problematic scenarios like the Windows 10 version 1809 release last month, because my rather conservative update configuration hadn't received that upgrade yet.