# Windows 10 freeze System to last stable Version

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803, windows-10-v1809

After update to 1809 and rollback to 1803 based of incompatible Graphic driver (Intel 4000) I will not run into the same issue again.
Is it possible to freeze Windows 10 to the last stable Version running smoothly?
Is there any tool available?

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deferring updates in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10)

Comment: That is not solving the problem - it is only postpone it...graphic driver will not longer supported by Intel! Postponing is not freezing! Solution can be make entry in the hosts file to link all update URLs to localhost...possible but not elegant.