# How to cancel a pending Windows Update in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, reboot

I have an important process running and I need to walk away from my computer for a few hours. However, I keep getting this popup prompting me to either restart my PC for a Windows update or delay the update by an hour.

Is there a way to cancel the update altogether?

[image: Windows Update warning]

Comment: If you are utilizing Windows 10 Professional, Enterprise, or Education, you can [pause updates within the Settings interface](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10/1199780#1199780) to cancel any pending updates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deferring updates in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10)

Comment: A temporary workaround is to choose "OK", Stop the Windows Update service in services.msc, and delete the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution folder.  It will start working again the next time you reboot (or earlier), download the update again, and give you the same ultimatum.  You can find other methods by searching this site, but beware that release version (1607, 1709, 1803, etc) and flavor (Home, Pro, Enterprise) will all give different abilities and options.

Comment: It would be a good idea to set Active Hours, if this is your personal computer. This setting tells Windows when you'd like the computer to be ready and not busy running background and maintenance tasks.

Comment: While I voted to close this as a duplicate, I feel the best approach, is to simply schedule when the update will be installed.  However, it is not clear, if you are using Window 10 Home or Windows 10 Professional