# Win10 Pro vs Win10 Home in a VM, what would I gain?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine

Considering purchasing a laptop, that comes with either Win10 Home or Win10 Pro.

The main OS in the laptop is going to be a Linux, but I sometimes need to run Windows apps, and so hope to transfer the forced-purchase license(*) to a VM. Given that the Win VM is going to be mostly a runtime environment for some apps, is there any benefit to have the Pro edition? Are there any apps that could refuse to run in a Family edition?

(*) no option to remove both in the configurator.

Comment: Article: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compare

Comment: That's just the MS propaganda :)

Comment: @xenoid - `Windows 10 Family Edition` does not exist.

Comment: From my perspective, one of the biggest benefits of utilizing Windows 10 Pro is the ability to [defer Feature Updates](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10/1199780#1199780) by several months to maintain a stable operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read trought some informative sites and there is no difference for what you want to do. And by that I mean normal apps, like Microsoft Office, AutoCad, etc;

Most differences [Here](https://www.xataka.com/basics/windows-10-home-vs-windows-10-pro-cuales-son-las-diferencias-entre-ambas-versiones) and [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/es-cl/windows/compare), point to less features on the networking and security side of Windows. You won't have Remote Desktop neither will you be able to join to a HomeGroup. Also there is a limitation on ram capacity wich is 128gb for Home a 2tb for the Pro. Being a laptop this shouldn't be a problem.

Also the most important thing is that you won't be able to run 16-bit apps on any Windows 10 version.

You must know this already but Wine have gone a long way and it's more compatible than it used to be. Install it and try to run your apps trought it. If that doesn't work then use the VM.

Cheers.