# How to use a router to access files without internet

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, network-shares, home-networking, file-sharing

Like title reads, I want to use a router to distribute contents of an external harddrive on a local network, but I keep finding suggestions of using ddns, which requires internet (at least I think so!)

Total amateur here, if a there is already an answer please point me to it to delete this post.

Comment: Check your router manual whenever it supports it (does it have USB ports?) if it doesn't you will have to use a second PC or similar attach the HDD and create a share like usual.

Comment: Hi, you should just connect the pc's to the router, then set up a Network group and share the drive. Make sure all are lan connected, or wifi connected. Some routers won't allow share between lan/wifi. One thing tho, is that most Windows systems can access this folders, except Windows 10 Home(or whatever is called the basic version)

Comment: Hi! What is your router model and manufacturer?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please take the [tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to get your first badge

Comment: @swaglordmcmuffin' hi! I have an Asus Bluecave

Comment: @dmb wow, I think I do have Win10 home...

Comment: @Seth was think of setting up a rasberry po just for that. But yet again, I know very little of that

Comment: Then please check the link I posted on [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1404520/win10-pro-vs-win10-home-in-a-vm-what-would-i-gain/1404530#1404530) Answer

Comment: @Seth but the router does have sharing capability. My problem is I dont know how to set it up :)

Comment: @dmb thank you! I'm just surprised by the amount and swiftness of responses. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAN (or Network settings): This is where you can change the local network settings, including the default IP address of the router itself. (Note that if you change the router's default IP address, which is recommended for security reason, you'll then need to use the new address to access the router's web interface.) Here you can also change the range of IP addresses used for local clients, and add clients to the DHCP Reservation list. Once on this list, the clients' IP addresses will remain the same, which is required for some internet applications. Most of the time, you don't need to change anything in this section at all. Just connect the pc's to the router. Then set a home group and check here - [Wireless network without internet](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2292354/setting-up-a-wireless-network-without-an-internet-connection.html)

Tools (or Administration) section

Admin password (or Password): Change the router's password. This is the password required when you log in the router's web interface.

System: Where you can back up the current settings of the router to a file, or restore settings from a file; update the router's firmware; and so on. It's always helpful to back up the router's settings before you make changes.

You'll find a lot more settings and features on a router's web interface, and when have time, you should try them out. If worst comes to worst, you can turn to the last-resort step below to restore the router to its default settings.