# Choose when updates are installed option missing - windows 10

Tags: windows-10-v1903

On normal system, I can see 
[image: choose when updates are installed option on advanced option on update settings.]

However, on my other system, 
[image: there's no such option.]

How can I bring those options back?

Both systems are Windows 10 19H1, one with the option is build 18362.295, one without the option is build 18362.239. However, I think the difference between those minor versions are not the cause since it was all the same throughout all previous minor versions.

edit:
[This question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10) is not about my case because, 1. it deals mainly about gpedit settings, 2. if settings on gpedit are having some effect, then those options would be greyed out as a screenshot on the answer post. However, in my case, those options are completely missing.

Comment: Are they both Windows 10 Pro?

Comment: Both Windows 10 Education

Comment: @Ramhound It's a different situation. By using gpedit, settings are greyed out, according to the link that you wrote. However, in my situation, settings are not showing at all.

Comment: @SunkyueKim - It's exactly the same case, your missing options, are due to the build level.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on one of three identically-configured computers (all the same build). I was able to use the Local Group Policy Editor to change the settings, per the supposed 'duplicate' question, but I agree with @SunkyueKim that the question has not been answered, and https://superuser.com/questions/1199677/deferring-updates-in-windows-10 is **not** a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the above suggestion to check if the one system is Windows 10

Quote "Windows 10 Home does not offer any deferral options."  See this article below for the resource

https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-update-act-fast-to-delay-this-big-upgrade/